# How to install ubuntu 12.04 and replace fedora. i have previously installed fedora apart from windows xp

Tags: linux, system-installation

How can I replace previously installed Fedora with Ubuntu 12.04?

My GRUB version is 0.97-71.fc15.

Comment: This is a very trivial question. Consider searching **Google** before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can boot using Ubuntu 12.04 live-cd/usb, and format the partition where Fedora was installed.

Then proceed to install Ubuntu on it after setting the partition with filesystem of your choice with proper mount points.